# Htaccess redirect rewrite rule custom url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

How would I do this please? I am having problems with my htaccess.

suppose I have this url:

```
www.testingstackzz.com/index.php?action=list&lcp=19
```

and I want to redirect it to a custom url which I made up like this

```
www.testingstackzz.com/general/place
```

where 'place' in the above url is the name for the variable lcp=19 in the database. So lcp=20 would be another place to be more explicit.

Answer (score 0):

In your `index.php` script, look for the `$_GET['lcp']` parameter, look it up in the database, then use `header("Location: /general/$name_of_place");`

If you only want to limit this to request that directly access the `index.php` file, then check the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`.